# Как проигнорировать знак - в input number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5

Есть поле `input type="number"` и кнопка при нажатию на которую данные с инпута, которые обрабатывает php, уходят в бд. нужно сделать следующее: чтобы при вводе с клавиатуры знака - он не учитывался при обработке скриптом после нажатия на кнопку. т.е. если пользователь ввел знак - первым символом, а потом цифры, то этот - должен игнорироваться. иначе баланс пользователя не уменьшается, а наоборот увеличивается

Вопрос: как это реализовать?

Пробовал некоторые варианты решений с гугла, но результата 0 или я что то не так делаю.
**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" name="creditoff">
    <button id="repaycredit" name="repaycredit" class="btn">погасить кредит</button>
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['repaycredit']) && $us_bal >= $creditoff) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET 
            balance = balance - :balcredit,
            credit = credit - :credit,
            status_credit = '1'
            WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $us_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':balcredit', $creditoff, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':credit', $creditoff, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: `$str = str_replace(['+', '-'], null, $str);`

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что хотите запретить именно вставку + и -, а не всех символов, большинство из которых и так не вставляется

Comment: Добавил изменения в оба ответа с защитой от вставки.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, Оба варианта имеют изъяны. Первый вариант никак не защищен и вставка символов. как работала, так и будет работать. А второй вариант, лишен души, вы запретили вставку мышкой, это беда, плохо и не серьезно, так поступать с пользователями, которые хотят именно, копировать текст и вставить его, а не набирать в ручную, большая часть человек, будет проходить мимо таких сайтов. цените время посетителей и активных пользователей.

Answer (score 3):

Если на js, то можно так:

```js
FU.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var s = e.keyCode;
    return (s > 47 && s < 58) || (s > 95 && s < 105) || (s > 32 && s < 41) || s == 8 || s == 46;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id="FU"/>
```

Если хотите на jquery, то так :

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.key.length == 1 && e.key.match(/[^0-9'".]/)){
        return false;
    };
})
$("#FU").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="FU"/>
```

Оба варианта с защитой от вставки данных из буфера.

Comment: Вариант так себе, ибо вставка мышкой отработает как пить дать. По этому не стоит забывать, что мышь тоже умеет текста вставлять. Лучше просто отслеживать изменение и не лепить туда тонну событий.

Answer (score 3):

ваш js запрет могут легко переделать и написать любой тип. вам нужно ставить проверку на php . и самый простой вариант это типизация переменной. например:
$num = (int)$_POST['mynumber'];

Comment: Вам ни о чем не говорит `PDO::PARAM_INT`? Типизация переменной и так есть. @ЮраБирюков, сделать при написании в `input`, через `php`, не получится. Так-как это нужно делать на стороне браузера, то есть через `JavaScript`, а если вы хотите, отправлять и делать это на сервере, то вам можно сделать через `preg_replace`. Но задача не совсем понятна.

Comment: @ЮраБирюков, нажмите [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1067549/edit) и измените свой вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать исчерпывающий ответ. А комменты следует удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать событие `oninput`.

```js
let input = document.body.children[0];
input.oninput = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
};
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

так все будет работать

```js
if (isset($_POST['repaycredit']) && $us_bal >= $creditoff) {
   if ($creditoff < 0) {
    echo "...";
   }
   else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET 
     balance = balance - :balcredit,
     credit = credit - :credit,
     status_credit = '1'
     WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $us_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':balcredit', $creditoff, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':credit', $creditoff, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
   }
  }
```